# Doubts about typecast "(String)anObject" and anotherString.value.length

Tags: java, string, equals

I am exploring the String API in Java I came across inside equals method

firstly,

```java
if (anObject instanceof String) {
    String anotherString = (String)anObject;
```

even after checking instanceOf String for an object it has been typecasted inside that condition, could you kindly help me understand this.

Secondly,

```java
String anotherString = (String)anObject;
int n = value.length;
if (n == anotherString.value.length)
```

Here why are we using `anotherString.value.length` not `anotherString.length`

**I tried** multiple sources like `JLS`, `Herbert Schildt` Book, but could not really decipher this. Kindly help me understand this better.

```java
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If strings have different lengths, it doesn't matter what values their char arrays hold. JLS won't say anything about this, because it's not a matter of JLS, it's just an implementation detail, and JLS is the _specification_. Using internal reference is just a microoptimization, Internal implementation shouldn't be forced to use the class's public methods.

Comment: because there is no `length` property in `String`. Calling `this.length()` you're adding extra invocation in a call stack which is not necessary as `String` is final.

Comment: @Salauyou Ohh !!!  Got it. Since we are creating a new String `anotherString` inside `String` class itself, we are optimizing by not calling the method length of this string `anotherString.length()`.  Could you kindly write the answer so that I can accept and close the question.  If you can add some info on `length` the variable - storing the array size at the time of any array object creation would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> even after checking instanceOf String for an object it has been typecasted inside that condition, could you kindly help me understand this.

Regardless of the `instanceof` check, you can't assign a value with type `Object` to a variable of type `String`. So `anObject` has to be typecast to assure the compiler that it's okay. (There is at least one language — TypeScript — whose compiler would be able to infer that the assignment was okay based on the `instanceof` check, but Java's compiler doesn't do that...[yet](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305).)

> Here why are we using anotherString.value.length not anotherString.length

`value` is the instance member within the `String` object containing the actual string data (as a `char[]` or `byte[]` array; it was `char[]` in JDK 1-8, it's `byte[]` in JDK 9+). It makes sense to use `value.length` because that's the length of the array; if the `value`s of the two strings aren't the same length, they can't be equal. To use `anotherString.length()` would require a pointless method call (remember, the public `length` is a *method*, not a field), which would just end up looking at `value.length` anyway (plus some overhead, at least in JDK11).

Comment: @tjcrowder When you say as a byte array[] are we talking about this _private final char value[]_

Comment: @KodeSaga - It depends which version of the JDK you're looking at. It's a `byte[]` in JDK 11. It used to be a `char[]`, the change from `char[]` to `byte[]` is relatively recent. I don't recall which specific version it was in.

Comment: The change happened in JDK 9.

Comment: @tjcrowder could you please add this part to the answer as it would complete my doubt with regard to on 'length' part in 'anotherString.value.length'. As per my understanding till now, it is a variable attached to any array at the time of its creation. "The array's length is available as a final instance variable length." - [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)

Comment: @KodeSaga - The `length` field (sometimes called an "instance variable" or "property") of an array is the length of the array. I've updated the final paragraph above a bit. Hope that helps.